# multiple hypothesis testing in a multilevel situation

Tags: multilevel-analysis, multiple-comparisons

I have the following situation.

I have `N_S` subjects, each subject `i` has `N_i` electrodes. I am measuring the Power Spectrum Density (PSD) in 4 different conditions (A, B, C, D), with about 100 trials in each condition. I want to find the frequencies and conditions at which the PSD is significantly different than in condition A.
Using the 100 trials and some test, I can get a p-values at each condition and frequency. I was thinking to then use the FDR to correct for multiple hypothesis testing.

I am then never sure what family of p-values to take when doing the FDR procedure. Is it all the p-values related to 1 electrode, 1 subject, all subjects/elecrodes/conditions/frequencies...?

I would appreciate any insights/thoughts on this. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.